# How to force the loop to perform another iteration to zero and close the loop?

Tags: c++

In the first example, the loop goes from zero to 9, but I don’t know how to do the same thing in reverse order only.

```
        size_t i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        { 
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
```

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Here is what I am trying to do but get the last number 1

```
        for (i = 9; i > 0; i--)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
```

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two canonical loop forms to remember and use in your code. I am using a `while` loop in both cases to show the difference better.

1. Looping up

```cpp
size_t counter = 0;
while (counter != 10)
{
    printf("%d\n", counter);

    ++counter;
}
```

2. Looping down

```
size_t counter = 10;
while (counter != 0)
{
    --counter;

    printf("%d\n", counter);
}
```

Edit: both forms work with either signed and unsigned loop counters.

Comment: Hmm, `size_t` matches `"%zu"`.

Comment: My bad, I edited to change the loop counter type, but forgot about the format...

Answer (score 2):

```
for (auto i = 9; i >= 0; --i)
     printf("%d\n", i);
```

Comment: Matter of taste, but I'd use `int i` to make the signed-ness more visible

Comment: Shadowing the original `i` works, but it seems OP wants to reuse the same variable.

Comment: Does C have `auto`?

Comment: It was a C++ question when @PickeRick answered :-)

Answer (score 0):

in your code, there is a potential error (on the descending loop) you are using size_t as the counter but size_t is an unsigned type that is it always higher than 0,
 and if by mistake it getting "under zero" it will go to MAX unsigned and it will continue to run.
so my suggestion is to use signed ver for loop counter (also unsigned arithmetic is more costly then signed one) and like it ansered to you

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<10 ; ++i)
{
     //some code
}

for(i=9; i>=0; --i)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: why use post-increment it does not work with loops. `--i`, `++i`

Comment: a force of habit and also on some data types it's more efficient
[link](http://softwareramblings.com/2010/01/post-increment-vs-pre-increment.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
   for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                printf("%d\n", i);
            }
```

Comment: It looks like OP is using an unsigned type for `i` so that won't work.